# asp.net content type problems after sending data

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, post

This is my code for send post query to the server:

```
public static HttpWebResponse PostMethod(string postedData, string postUrl)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(postUrl);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        var bytes = encoding.GetBytes(postedData);

        //request.ContentType = "application/javascript";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        //request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        //request.ContentType = "application/json";
        //request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";

        request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

        using (var newStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            newStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            newStream.Close();
        }
        return (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    }
```

And ActionResult:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SendMessage(FEEDBACK feedbackModel)
    {
        MessageData msgData = new MessageData();

        msgData.to = "zicise@mail.ru";
        msgData.from = feedbackModel.sEmail;
        msgData.title = "Сообщение с сайта наркома от пользователя: " + feedbackModel.vFIO;
        msgData.message = feedbackModel.vFIO;

        var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(msgData);

        var response = PostMethod("to=zicise@mail.ru&from=narkom@info.by&title=Second method&message=test message", "http://projects.pushnovn.com/send_email/");
        //var response = PostMethod("to:zicise@mail.ru,from:narkom@info.by,title:Second method,message:test message", "http://projects.pushnovn.com/send_email/");
        //var response = PostMethod("{to:zicise@mail.ru,from:narkom@info.by,title:Second method,message:test message}", "http://projects.pushnovn.com/send_email/");
        //var response = PostMethod("[{to:zicise@mail.ru,from:narkom@info.by,title:Second method,message:test message}]", "http://projects.pushnovn.com/send_email/");
        //var response = PostMethod(jsonString, "http://projects.pushnovn.com/send_email/");

        if (response != null)
        {
            var strreader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
            var responseToString = strreader.ReadToEnd();

            RootObject r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseToString);

            ViewBag.RedirectMessage = r.msg;
        }

        return View("~/Views/Home/RedirectPage.cshtml");
    }
```

But this code worked only when I send data in format: `to=zicise@mail.ru&from=narkom@info.by&title=Second method&message=test message` and he is broken when I try to cut my custom string like: `"to="+value+"&from="+value+"&title="+value+"&message="+value`

But I need to send data from model and get 0 answer. After that PHP script send me email with data. Anyone know, how to convert object in json format `name=value&name=value`

Maybe I need to change Content Type and send jsonString to the server? But if that true, what format I need to use?

Comment: What is the value (after concatenating) of `"to="+value+"&from="+value+"&title="+value+"&message="+value`?

Comment: e.g. `string postData = "to=zicise@mail.ru"
                + "&from=" + feedbackModel.sEmail.ToString() 
                + "&title=" + feedbackModel.vFIO.ToString() 
                + "&message" + feedbackModel.vMessage.ToString();` when I use this string method send Me 0, but email didn't send.

Comment: `to=zicise@mail.ru&from=example@mail.ru&title=Ivan Ivanov&message=message`

Answer (score 0):

You need to URL encode the data.

```
"to="+value+"&from="+value+"&title="+value+"&message="+value
```

should be changed to:

```
"to="+HttpUtility.UrlEncode (value)+"&from="+HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value)+"&title="+HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value)+"&message="+HttpUtility.UrlEncode (value)
```

Comment: It's not work. I have 0 and server don't send me email. Work only custom message.

Comment: When you debug through the server side code, are there any exceptions? Anything not acting as you expect?

Comment: `{"code":0,"msg":"\u0421\u043e\u043e\u0431\u0449\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u0443\u0441\u043f\u0435\u0448\u043d\u043e \u043e\u0442\u043f\u0440\u0430\u0432\u043b\u0435\u043d\u043e!"}` this string server send Me when I debug the project.